# How to calculate the shape from lon/lat coordinates and draw it with plotly

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly, shapely

I have a `plotly` based map where I am showing several coordinates in a Mapbox scatter plot. Now I want to get a shape from these coordinates and draw a shape on the map.

The coordinates are available as a `pandas.Series`. Below an extract of the coordinates.

```
0    [[51.795, 3.363], [51.79483333333334, 3.363], ...
1    [[51.42536, 2.622246666666667], [51.4256883333 ...
```

How can I get a shape for these coordinates which boundaries are the outmost coordinates of the cluster?

[image]

Comment: `How can I get the outside shape of these coordinates?` Please elaborate. What does 'outside shape' mean to you? What would you expect in the example case? Are you looking for the 'convex hull'?

Comment: The screenshot illustrates the shape - I know not in the best way, With outside shape I mean a shape that represents the outmost coordinates of the showed coordinate cluster.

Comment: Alright, convex hull it is then. If the cluster is small, meaning that the curvature of earth is not a concern, then a standard convex hull algorithm should be fine with directly feeding gps coordinates to it. SciPy has one.

Comment: Perfect. Sounds interesting. Could you provide a kick-off example?

Comment: I'm on mobile unfortunately, but it should be pretty much a oneliner: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.ConvexHull.html Feel free to post an answer based in this on your own question.

Comment: Thanks, I will try it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In geometry, there are basically two main concepts [Convex hull](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull) and [Alpha shape](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_shape) (also called Concave hull) to get the shape of a finite set of points. The following picture should visually describe the differences between them [[2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_shape)].

[image]

In case you want to have the convex hull you can use `scipy.spatial.ConvexHull` [[4](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.ConvexHull.html)].

As alternatives to `scipy` you can also check [geopandas](https://geopandas.org/#) and [alphashape](https://pypi.org/project/alphashape/).

Comment: this `alphashape` is hell of a slow function if you don't use alpha parameter.